# Create sub section within section of Dynamics CRM 2011 - Form Editor

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, form-editing

I am assigned with a task of adding subsection within section of MS CRM 2011 - Form Editor.

**Description:**
I can't find any default way of adding Nested Sections. Searching it on internet, I found that we can do it by changing XML that is being built in background but I can't find any way of importing and exporting XML.

I came across this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327975(v=crm.5).aspx) but this doesn't help.

Please let me know how can I achieve this in **Dynamics CRM 2011**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested sections - Why would you do that? Its highly dangerous UNSUPPORTED customization. You may need to touch these.

[Form XML Schema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309601(v=crm.5).aspx) and [`<sections>` (FormXml)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328314(v=crm.5).aspx)

```
<xs:element name="sections" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="section" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
```

What I would recommend is try to achieve it with [Tabs & Sections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334527(v=crm.5).aspx#BKMK_MajorFormElements). Tabs are collapsible & hide-able.

Otherwise you can add a HTML web resource & do the styling the way you want using CSS, etc.